# Comparing file name to string

Tags: java, file

I have hit a road block in a program I am writing in Java. The program basically copies folders and files from multiple locations into one folder to make backing up code from multiple locations on my computer easier. The problem I have is that I don't want to copy specific folders, in this case "`workspace/.metadata`". The start of the code I am having issues with is below:

```
public void copyFolder(File in, File out, String loc)
        throws IOException{

        String check = in.getName().substring(1);
        System.out.println("loc:"+loc+"check: "+check);
        if(loc.equals("java")){
            if(check.equals("metadata")){
                System.out.println("failboat");
                //statusBox.append("failboat");
            }
}
```

And this is the result I see:

```
loc:java
check: orkspace2
loc:java
check: metadata
loc:java
check: lock
```

I've had other's look at the code and they agree it should work. I've even created a replica of the code in a test file:

```
String test = "fmetadata";
    String loc = "java";
    String check = test.substring(1);
    if(loc.equals("java")){
        if(check.equals("metadata")){
            System.out.print("failboat");
        }else{
            System.out.println("WTF");
            System.out.print(test+ ": :"+check); 
        }
}
```

And the result?

```
failboat
```

There is a dent in my desk the size of my forehead from trying to figure this out.

Comment: Shortly after posting this I found that newline escape sequence. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that output you posted is the actual output:

```
loc:java
check: orkspace2
loc:java
check: metadata
loc:java
check: lock
```

It does not match the code you've pasted, as you do not print a newline between the two items:

```
System.out.println("loc:"+loc+"check: "+check);
```

If this is truly what you are seeing with that code then I would say the problem is that `loc` has a stray newline at the end, and is actually "java\n" rather than "java" as you expect. So you should go back and examine how you generate the value you pass through `loc` to begin with before calling that function.

---

If this is the case, some suggestions for diagnostics improvements that could help you notice these kinds of issues sooner (in addition to stepping through with a debugger):

```
// quote your strings to spot whitespace, print length to spot unexpected
// unprintable characters.
System.out.println("loc: \""+loc+"\" "+loc.length());
System.out.println("check: \""+check+"\" "+check.length());
```

And:

```
if(loc.equals("java")){
    // make sure you're getting to this point, don't assume that the first
    // if condition was satisfied:
    System.out.println("grumpycat"); // <----
    if(check.equals("metadata")){
        System.out.println("failboat");
    }
}
```